# Mysql Query Select data on multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm now doing **four** separate queries to select the information i need.

f.e.

```
SELECT value FROM data where sensor=123 AND value_id=a
SELECT value FROM data where sensor=123 AND value_id=b
SELECT value FROM data where sensor=123 AND value_id=c
SELECT value FROM data where sensor=123 AND value_id=d
```

Now i'm experementing with some code. I don't know if on my right way but is such a thing possible:

```
SELECT value180,value181,value182,value183
        FROM (
            SELECT
            MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) as value180,
            MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) as value181,
            MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) as value182,
            MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) as value183
            FROM data
            WHERE sensor_id = 1605850
            AND value_id IN ("1.8.0","1.8.1","1.8.2","1.8.3")
        ) a
```

It would be nice to have a single query...thx for helping in advance!

note: i have to use max value of each day per sensor per value. In the above first example this max function was just left out for simplification.

This is the table how it looks like:
[image]

as you can see there are **hourly taken values** for each value_id.

What i need:
I need the **highest value of yesterday for defined value_id's**.

f.e. 1.8.0 = 3726.12, 1.8.1 = 663.69, ...

With my combined query i'm getting **wrong values** but the **format** how i want to get the values **is correct**:

[image]

Comment: Those two achieve very different things... maybe if you explain what you want to get and the tables you are getting it from

Comment: You query should work fine. Are you getting any issue

Comment: No i don't get an error but i'm only getting one and the same value for each value. (value180,value181,value182,value183 = all the same value). I need the value of a in value180 and so on ...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
SELECT  value FROM data
WHERE sensor=123 AND value_id IN ('a', 'b', 'c' , 'd');
```

or

```
SELECT value FROM data
WHERE sensor=123 AND value_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT value_id FROM data);
```

Comment: I would also add a `GROUP BY` option

Comment: This is not the correct answer to the question. Plesae read it once again.

Comment: he specified that  ` I don't know if on my right way ` and now he is doing with 4 line of code. My answer is for that.

Comment: I need exact four values back therefore i can fetch them in php. -> value180,value181,value182,value183. This solution bring only one value back with multiple entries.

Comment: please add your table and required fields

Answer (score 0):

After a short walk through the nature to take a pause i was able to solve my problem.

```
SELECT
(SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) FROM data WHERE sensor_id = 1605850 AND value_id = "1.8.0") as value180,
(SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) FROM data WHERE sensor_id = 1605850 AND value_id = "1.8.1") as value181,
(SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) FROM data WHERE sensor_id = 1605850 AND value_id = "1.8.2") as value182,
(SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN DATE(time) = subdate(CURDATE(), 1) THEN value ELSE 0 END) FROM data WHERE sensor_id = 1605850 AND value_id = "1.8.3") as value183
```

that was all.